# CosmosDB insert item with specific ID

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I was wondering if it is possible to specific the ID when inserting a new object on Cosmos DB.

```
this.container.items
      .create<Session>(session)
      .then(() => callback(null))
      .catch((error) => callback(error));
```

Is it possible to specify the ID when inserting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is specified in the object, in your case, the `session` object:

```
interface Session{
  id: string;
  // other properties
}

let session : Session = {
    id: "myId",
    // other properties
  };

this.container.items
      .create<Session>(session)
      .then(() => callback(null))
      .catch((error) => callback(error));
```